# encode a list of numbers into a value (compression) while considering the order of the elements

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

this is using the R programming language.
i was wondering if there is a way in which one can encode a list or array of digits into a single value...

what i mean is, if given lists of numbers [1,2,3,4,5] and [5,4,3,2,1] and/or [1,2,5,4,3], one can do calculation on all three sequences and get different results showing that they are not the same(the order matters). i.e get an answer with a sign or something...

is there a formula or a process i can use to achieve this...

ps:

i have tried std, variance, mean, g-mean, h-mean e.t.c and they all give the same result.

this is just an example... the values in the list can be any real number. concatenating the elements can only results to a string not a number ie [1,2,3.4,4.3,5]

EDIT:

its a dataframe where the rows contain positional element which represent a list of 32 elements(the labels/headers of these list are different but similar across other list) and each row has 11 elements... i.e my datafame [q,w,e,r,t,y] where q = [1,2,3,4] and w=[2,3,4,2.4] etc.. the headers of q, w, e, r, t, y are the same in the same order... by placing the list themselves inside the dataframe will only add more columns and this is what i am trying to avoid...

Comment: Say that you store values as $32$ bit ints in a computer and you know they can't be larger than $9$, then one way would be to concatenate the digits. $[1,2,3,4,5] \to 12345$ suddenly you get away with storing $1$ int instead of $5$ ints.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you added more details on what these numbers represent. For example, if the numbers that appear earlier in the list are more important, you could try something like a weighted average with the earlier numbers having higher weights.

Comment: these elements represent measurement taken in an experiment during different conditions... so each value is just as important as the next...

Comment: Presumably you mean the numbers in the list include some non-integer values, such as 32-bit floating-point data on a computer. But unless you have some relevant information that you're not telling us, you have no guarantee that you can encode the numbers in less computer memory than the original list occupied. Why can't you just compare the arrays element by element?

Comment: its a dataframe where the rows contain positional element which represent a list of 32 elements(the labels/headers of these list are different but similar across other list) and each row has 11 elements... i.e my datafame [q,w,e,r,t,y] where q = [1,2,3,4] and w=[2,3,4,2.4] etc.. the headers of q, w, e, r, t, y are the same in the same order... by placing the list themselves inside the dataframe will only add more columns and this is what i am trying to avoid...